# Khan Academy API displayed on Geektool

Tags: api, khan-academy

I have been experimenting with the Khan Academy API found here

> http://api-explorer.khanacademy.org/api/v1/user

and tried to find a way to display a user's points (and maybe some other information) on the desktop using geektool. I tried this

> stackoverflow.com/questions/12514722/khan-academy-php-oauth-code

and

> github.com/Khan/khan-api/

but nothing seems to work. The first link is the khan academy API provided as is. The second is someone with a similar problem who found a solution. He wrote a PHP script according to the temboo library and said to replace a few fields of the PHP and add both the PHP and the Temboo source code to the webroot. So, I added a folder called "php-sdk" into the webroot which is in /Library/WebServer/Documents/ and inside that folder was another folder "src" which contained the Khan Academy API and the Temboo library. Here is what I had.

> cl.ly/image/2c2Z1B3T443L

Then I took a look at [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3UOXIEWqPCw) and followed the steps until 6:19. Then I started the Apache server by entering this in terminal...

> sudo apachectl restart

I opened a web browser, and typed in this...

> localhost/php-sdk/src/khanAcademy.php

and I got this...

> Warning: require(php-sdk/src/temboo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/khanAcademy.php on line 66
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'php-sdk/src/temboo.php' (include_path='.:') in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/khanAcademy.php on line 66

any ideas on what this could mean or how I could fix this? I am not advanced in PHP, or python, but I really would love to find a solution to this problem and I am willing to try anything that might work.

Comment: I work at Temboo. 

Please feel free to contact support@temboo.com and we'll do our best to help figure this out. It would be great if you could include the PHP source file that you're trying to run. 

Thanks a lot,
Cormac

Answer (score 0):

This error:

```
Warning: require(php-sdk/src/temboo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/khanAcademy.php on line 66
```

indicates that the path you're using for `require` is likely incorrect. Currently your PHP is trying to find a file called `temboo.php` here:

```
/Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/php-sdk/src/temboo.php
```

Note the repeated directory structure. I'll make an assumption that your `temboo.php` is in the same directory as your `khanAcademy.php` file.  In that case, simply change `require "php-sdk/src/temboo.php"` to `require "temboo.php"`.  If my assumption is incorrect, just adjust the include path accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for that, now it doesn't give the same error when i write
require "temboo.php";
require "khanacademy.php";
but now it gives this error...
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare initializeOAuth() (previously declared in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/khanAcademy.php:105) in /Library/WebServer/Documents/php-sdk/src/khanacademy.php on line 127

Comment: You've declared two functions called `initializeOAuth` it sounds like.